# How to have a constructor that accepts an interface?

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn Java by doing some coding challenges. I can sort of understand the concepts by reading the theory but cannot appy them to coding problems, for some reason.

I have written an interface and now need to write a constructor in the AlertService class, that accepts this interface (AlertDAO). I don't really understand the concept.

Can anyone explain?

I've added the interface and added a constructor but not sure how to make that constructor ACCEPT the new interface? Hope I am making sense.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

class AlertService {
    private final MapAlertDAO storage = new MapAlertDAO();

    public UUID raiseAlert() {
        return this.storage.addAlert(new Date());
    }

    public Date getAlertTime(UUID id) {
        return this.storage.getAlert(id);
    }

}

interface AlertDAO {

    public UUID addAlert(Date time);
    public Date getAlert(UUID id);

}

class MapAlertDAO implements AlertDAO {
    private final Map<UUID, Date> alerts = new HashMap<UUID, Date>();

    public UUID addAlert(Date time) {
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        this.alerts.put(id, time);
        return id;
    }

    public Date getAlert(UUID id) {
        return this.alerts.get(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: `public AlertService(AlertDAO ad)`?

Comment: Sounds like you don't know what the word "accepts" means in this context. It means that it takes an `AlertDAO` as a parameter. See Federico's comment above.

Comment: you can do that by passing interface in constructor parameter or setting it using setter/getter. You can study more about it in this blog https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-quick-intro-to-dependency-injection-what-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-7578c84fa88f

Comment: @nsonline why? `AlertService` is not an `AlertDAO`, it *has* an `AlertDAO`. That's an imprortant disctincion and the reason why a lot of OO code sucks.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - Okay fine, but `MapAlertDAO` has `AlertDAO` implemented, and he's also creating `MapAlertDAO()` in `AlertService`, why the need for both? Why not pass in `MapAlertDAO` in the constructor and call the interface methods when you need them.

Comment: @nsonline That's a different issue. Probably the correct way to do this would be to have `storage` declared as an `AlertDAO`. If we kept it as `MapAlertDAO`, `AlertDAO` would be completely useless (in the context shown here) and this question wouldn't exist to begin with :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The constructor of the AlertService is:

```
public AlertService() {
}
```

A constructor is for creating a object of the class, like this:

```
AlertService alertService = new AlertService();
```

If you want to add the AlertDAO to the constructor, it looks like this:

```
public AlertService(AlertDAO alert){
    // do something with alert
}
```

A constructor in Java is a special method that is used to initialize objects. The constructor is called when an object of a class is created. It can be used to set initial values for object attributes
ref: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_constructors.asp

Edit:
If you want to have the AlertService class using the interface instead of the MapAlertDAO, use it like this:

```
class AlertService {
    private AlertDAO storage;

    public AlertService(AlertDAO alert) {
        this.storage = alert;
    }

    public UUID raiseAlert() {
        return this.storage.addAlert(new Date());
    }

    public Date getAlertTime(UUID id) {
        return this.storage.getAlert(id);
    }

}
```

Now you can pass your MapAlertDAO to the AlertService.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I guess I still need to plug away at understanding these concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Change the AlertService-class in this way:

```java
class AlertService {
    private final AlertDAO storage;

    public AlertService(AlertDAO alertDAO){
        storage = alertDAO;
    }

    public UUID raiseAlert() {
        return this.storage.addAlert(new Date());
    }

    public Date getAlertTime(UUID id) {
        return this.storage.getAlert(id);
    }

}
```

Then you can pass in an implementation of your AlertDAO-interface to the constructor of your AlertService-class, when you are creating an object of it in any other class.
For example:

```java
public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        AlertService alertService = new AlertService(new MapAlertDAO());
    }
}
```